# What is the best practice for writing Registry calls/File Sytem calls/Process creation filter for WinXP, Vista?

Tags: winapi, drivers

We needed to monitor all processes Registry calls/File Sytem calls/Process creations in the system (for the antivirus hips module) .

Also time by time it will be needed to delay some calls or decline them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported method of doing this is [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892.aspx)

Most virus checkers likely perform some sort of API hooking instead of using this function.  There's lots of information out there about API hooking, like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx, http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/misc/article.php/c5667